# Raspberry Pi 3 B not working after interrupting the Raspbian Upgrade

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, bash, failure

I was upgrading my ADC Hat mounted(no other sensors), Raspberry Pi 3 B (Stretch installed) using;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

During the middle of the upgrade, there was a message with some information(which I couldn't remember exactly) and as per the option provided I pressed 'q' to quit. Then the upgrade continued again quite a long time.

I interrupted it in the middle and shut down the Pi. Then removed the ADC and restarted the Pi.

**Unfortunately, now my Pi is not a working.No response to keyboard, mouse, taskbar not visible but the desktop(image) and the icons/folders are visible.** :(.I have restarted the Pi several time by powering on/off, still the same no response.

I have captured the messages during the boot and it is as below. 
[image]

Any help or guidance to fix this issue "Failed to start load kernel modules", please? Though I tried to open the command line to try solutions I'm unable to open the cmd by CTRL+ALT+F1 since no keyboard response.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your only option is to re-flash your SD Card.

Comment: Oo then I will lose all the documents inside that isn't it?  I'm sorry is there any option to save them?

Comment: Flash a new sd card and then you may be able to copy files from the old card with a usb sd card adapter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will try this and re-flash the SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that the all the data in your home directory is almost certainly still there.

DO NOT reformat the SD Card - it will be readable in any Linux OS (including Raspbian).

Take this as a lesson to backup your data before updating.

Comment: Yes, data in the home directory is still available and I have copied them using USB -SD card adapter.

Thank you very much, for your guidance. 
Yes... I will make sure to "backup data".